# SumIf with lots of data in Excel

Tags: excel, sumifs

what I'm trying to do is a simple sumif for about 200k lines of data which causes problems for excel.
Basically my list looks like this

```
List of Companies    Dummy1  Dummy2  
Company A             0       1
Company A             0       1
Company A             1       1 
Company B             1       1
Company B             0       1
Company B             0       1
....
```

and if there is a 1 in any row of column B for a specific company I need to plug a 1 in each row of column C for this company.
So Dummy 2 is basically the sum over Dummy 1 for all entries for a specific company. 
The data is already sorted by column A.
Anyway, Excel goes crazy.
Is it just plain stupid what I'm doing here because I'm generating too many comparative operations? 
What would be an easy way to accomplish what I'm trying to do here?

Comment: right now I'm doing this with a sumif. The problem is just that excel is calculating forever and crashing.

Comment: Well, summing over Dummy 1 for every company. Something like SUMIF(A:A, A, B:B)

Comment: Yes, I tried that. Did not help much. See my other comment below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your sample data, filling C2:C200000 with,

`=SUMIF(A:A, A2, B:B)`

... will be performing 3× as many `SUMIF` calculations as is necessary. An `IF` formula only processes the part that is TRUE or FALSE depending on how the criteria resolves so changing the formula to something like the following,

`=IF(A2<>A1, SUMIF(A:A, A2, B:B), C1)`

... should drastically reduce the processing in a calculation cycle. The degree of improvement will depend upon how many duplicate company values are in column A and whether column A has been sorted to keep the company names together. The smaller the number of unique companies, the more improvement you will see. In short, unless the company changes from row to row, the `SUMIF` is not calculated.

Sample Calculation Timing Environment:

- Excel 2010 64-bit (14.0.7015.1000) running under Windows 7 Pro on a business class i5 laptop w/8Gbs DRAM.
- XLSB; Calculation Manual; Recalculate workbook before saving OFF; Save AutoRecovery information OFF

**Test 1:** 26 companies (Company A to Company Z), each with ~7683 entries in column A, sorted. Column B random 0's and 1's reverted to values. C2:C200000 cleared, worksheet calculated then formula filled in C2:C200000 and new calculation cycle timed to completion.

```
 formula                                        calculation cycle (hh:mm:ss)
=SUMIF(A:A, A2, B:B)                                    00:21:44
=IF(A2<>A1, SUMIF(A:A, A2, B:B), C1)                    00:00:09
```

**Test 2:** 5000 companies (Company 0001 to Company 5000), each with ~40 entries in column A, sorted. Column B random 0's and 1's reverted to values. C2:C200000 cleared, worksheet calculated then formula filled in C2:C200000 and new calculation cycle timed to completion.

```
 formula                                        calculation cycle (hh:mm:ss)
=SUMIF(A:A, A2, B:B)                                    00:22:10
=IF(A2<>A1, SUMIF(A:A, A2, B:B), C1)                    00:00:37
```

[image: Elapsed time for calculation]

You cannot magically break the physical laws of time and space but sometimes you can fool them. This solution may not be perfect but perhaps it is something that you can live with.

On a related note, large(r) worksheets benefit from having their formulas reverted to result values once calculations have been made if those results are not likely to change on a regular basis. While *Copy, Paste Special, Values* is a reasonably quick method of accomplishing this, selecting a large number of cells containing formulas and running the following sub macro is lightning quick.

```
sub sel_2_Value
    application.enableevents = false
    selection = selection.value
    application.enableevents = true
end sub
```

If locale differences are not important (currency, dates, etc) then `selection = selection.value2` is even better.

The only thing that will slow down the above operation is formulas with dependents within the range being reverted to values as they will be recalculated.

Comment: Thanks for you help! Yes, your little "trick" what was I somehow did not come of with. Another problem that I had was that used the data in data table. I think converting the table to a range of data + minimizing the calculations with your trick already helped a bit. I ended up doing basically the same in VBA and now I'm fine and it hardly takes a second to do the work. What still makes me think: For fun I tested my "original idea", i.e. without your trick, in VBA and and it also works perfectly fine and does not take long either.

Answer (score 1):

I think the better way to solve this is by ussing pivot table, you can sum Dummy1 by company and get the data as summary.

Here is an examples:

http://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/pivot-tables.html

[enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vx-Fuw46VbY)

I hope this help

Comment: Hi, thanks for you help! That is actually a good point, because I used a pivot table that just did what I wanted and it did not take any time to "calculate" the pivot table. However, for reasons the pivot table is not enough.